# How to make uiscrollview only vertical scrolling for ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm trying to make `layout` inside `scrollview` using this one [tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnQsFlMGDsI)

And get the following result [link](http://youtu.be/iPfzyLbEZMA)

It will be appreciated for any advices or tutorial links. It needs only vertical scrolling

Comment: I can't see your second video. And try to post here the problem instead of leading us to other link

Comment: A scrollview's scrolling depends on its contentSize.

Comment: i think your UIScrollView width is more then screen width that why horizonal scrolling happen. try to make exact width as screen have.

Comment: just make scrollview's content view `equalwidth` with its `superview`

Comment: Yes, i did it, equal width, and equal height with low prioprity... Looks like poltergeist, but really know here is a some small issue (((

Comment: tell us what constraints you are adding on scrollView and the content Uiview ..

Comment: 1. Common screenshot [link](http://joxi.ru/MAjMM4jt1YXQ2e)

2. For scrollview and the same for contentview [link](http://joxi.ru/VrwQQ4ZcjgJN2X)

3. Contentview to SuperView equal width and height, but height with low priority

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am sure there must be other ways to do this but a quick fix is :

1.) Create a width constraint on ContentView in Storyborad.

2.) IBOutlet that widthContraint and set its value to the view frame  width in viewDidLoad.

Suppose the name of the constraint outlet is contentViewWidthContraint.

```
contentViewWidthContraint.constant = self.view.bounds.size.width;
```

---

Another alternative to do so from Storyboard, is to fix the Contentview width to the view's width from the storyboard or to the Scrollview, if Scrollview already has a Equal width contraint with superview . Add the "Equal Width" contraint from Contentview to either self.view or to Scrollview (if scrollview, already has the width contraint)

Comment: I tried this, and it seemed to fix it. But - in Xcode 10 there is a checkbox that enables `Safe Area Relative Margins`. With that unchecked, one of my UITextViews were wider than the view, causing it to be scrollable vertically as well as horizontally. Checking it however, restricted the scrollview to vertical only.

Answer (score 11):

Have you set up the "ContentView" width to match with the scroll view width? I had the same problem and I fixed with "**Equal Widths**".

"**Equal Widths**" will tell to your "ContentView" to use the same width of the "Scroll View", which should be fitting the screen if you have set up the constrain properly.

You can do this easily on the storyboard.

1. Drag and drop, with right click (important!!!), from "ContentView" to "ScrollView"
2. Release the click, you will be prompted with a menu, select "**Equal Widths**".

   [image: Prompted menu]

This should fix your problem using the scrollview with AutoLayout from Storyboard editor.

You can find a full tutorial how to use ScrollView with Autolayout and Storyboard [here](http://easydebug.blogspot.com/2015/06/ios-scroll-view-using-auto-layout.html).

I hope this is useful for you :)

Comment: Thing that helped me about this answer was embedding my labels inside of a view and trying to get the scrollview working with that single view.

Answer (score 3):

In the Storyboard set the width of the elements contained in your UIScrollView equal to the width of this UIScrollView (by selecting all elements and the UIScrollView holding  in the panel on the left of your Storyboard and then setting the 'Equal Widths' constraint under 'Pin' on the bottom of your Storyboard). Just pinning the right sides of the elements to that of the UIScrollView won't work as it will adjust the size of its "display view" to the width of the largest element and if this is smaller than the width of the UIScrollView all elements will just appear aligned to its left side.

Answer (score 3):

There is also another possibility that offers a very good result.

You can mark a checkbox:

[image]

O programmatically:

```
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set it's width to 0 & height equal to content size like this:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, self.scrollView.contentSize.height);
```

This will work as you want. Try it & tell if still facing any issue.

Comment: Could you please post your code related to your scroll view?

Comment: All designed in storyboard using constraits

Comment: 1. Common screenshot link 2. For scrollview and the same for contentview link 3. Contentview to SuperView equal width and height, but height with low priority

Answer (score 1):

For disabling the horizontal scroll, you can set the content size in the `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll` method.

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentOffset.y)];
self.scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because scroll view have no idea where your content should end.

But when at least one item inside your scroll view has its "trailing space" constraint attached to a view outside the scroll view (usually a view the scroll view is sitting in or some other view of a higher level, which "knows" its width) - the scroll view will automatically get an idea about your wanted width and won't scroll horizontally (unless that trailing constraint implies having your content outside the screen).

Better if all items inside scroll view have their "trailing space" constraints connected either to each other or to a view outside the scroll view. But not the scroll view itself.

No additional code or extra constraints needed for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Too set `UIScrollView` constraints as like below code so it will occupied whole screen.Not exceed the screen size.

```
Leading Space = 0 from mainView
Top Space = 0 from mainView
Bottom Space = 0 from mainView 
Trailing Space = 0 from mainView
```

Comment: @AlexeyZakevich, can you please add screen shot of setting layout of UIScrollView? if you dont have any issue.

Comment: @AlexeyZakevich, Applied same layout contraint to UIView that is inside ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width of UIScrollView equal to or less than the width of your Parent View. Two ways to do it:

1) You can do this in Storyboard via layout constraints

2) You can do this programatically:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.contentSize.height);
```

Comment: trying first and second one, but still facing issue